# Which technology to use to set the alarm at Swift for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, uilocalnotification, alarm

I do alarm clock app. That is my view:

[image]

**What is already working:**

I make single tap on "6:00", which call my function `addAlarm ("6:00", "unstable")`. Button "6:00" was highlighted in green. Time itself was stored in the data model of the application, to the button with this time will be highlight after closing and reopening the application.

Button "8:00" is red, because I make double tap on it, which call function `addAlarm ("6:00", "stable")`. Information was also recorded in the data model.

**What I want:**

The green color of the button "6:00" means that the alarm should triggered once at 6 am, and then has to be deactivated: the button again to become blue. I have function for it `removeAlarm(time)`

Red Button "8:00" means that the alarm should be triggered each day at 8 am, but after that the button should also be red.

Under the «alarm should be triggered», I mean the following. On the screen of the device should be the notice with text «Wake up», and begins to play a tune. The file with the tune has 20 seconds duration, but I want play tune 3 minutes, constantly repeating 20 second file with the tune.

Alarm should be triggered even when the application is minimized, the phone is in sleep mode, or set to "Not disturb".

**What I do not understand:**

Well, of course, how to do what I want :-) But seriously, I am not clear what methods to use. I managed to find the following.

I can use [NSTimer](http://makeapppie.com/2015/04/24/swift-swift-using-nstimer-to-make-a-timer-or-alarm/), to call some callback after the appointed time, but the timers stop working after 10 minutes after minimizing the application.

I can and should use the [UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/local-notifications-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/) for the appearance of the notice, but the melody for the notice may not be longer then 30 seconds. Also not clear to me, as I call my function `removeAlarm (time)` for the alarm, which was created for single time working, if the user does not respond to the notification, for example, will not wake up.

I can use the [Background Modes](http://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial).

**In general, the question is:**

What is, or what methods I should to use, how to combine them, and which direction is best to choose?

Comment: Most alarm app will need to be kept in foreground to work. I believe that's the reason why iOS clock's alarm has advantage.

Comment: Since the question has been asked almost a year ago, did you get one of these approaches to work?

Comment: I have not finished that app, so not all issues was resolved. For settings alarms I used UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification) for multiple times. For example: if I need alarm at 8:00, playing 3 minutes, mp3 file 20 seconds duration, then I set 9 notifications at 8:00, 8:00:20, 8:00:40, 8:01, 8:01:20... I am not iOS developer, what I can say :–)